# fullcalendar : calender not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Calendar not displaying. i am not getting any error. please help me to solve this issue.

HTML Code is as following:

```
<div class="card-box">
   <div id='calendar' align="center" style="background-color: rgb(244, 247, 249); padding: 25px; margin: 0px;"></div>
</div>


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        disableDragging: false,
        editable: false,
        selectable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        views: {
            agendaTwoDay: {
                type: 'agenda',
                duration: { days: 2 },
                groupByResource: true,
                groupByDateAndResource: true
            }
        },
        allDaySlot: false,
        resources: ConfRoomArrayDisplay,
        events: MeetingArrayDisplay,
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            //code for render section
        },
        eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
            $(element).removeClass("fc-short");
        }
    });
```

event json format is as following:

```
MeetingArrayDisplay ="[{"id":"09CCDDE2-75FA-401A-B52D-23094809D3BF","resourceId":"1","start":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","title":"Weekly project review meeting","UserID":"6","Attendees":"","Repeated":"-","UserName":"tsa","url":"Javascript:"},{"id":"4E7E7C5A-04EA-4090-BCFB-5D3002233663","resourceId":"1","start":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","title":"project","UserID":"6","Attendees":"","Repeated":"-","UserName":"tsd","url":"Javascript:"}]"
```

calendar render event call as following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', MeetingArrayDisplay);
```

[image]

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there is not any error @ mic4ael

Comment: you have a `debugger` statement in there. It will break out into the debugger

Comment: no it is not reach up to debugger @KScandrett

Comment: Take out all the stuff you don't need to get it to show and then start putting things back. That will tell you where the problem is

Comment: `MeetingArrayDisplay ="[{"id":"09CCDDE2-75FA-401A-B52D-23094809D3BF","resourceId":"1","start":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","title":"Weekly project review meeting","UserID":"6","Attendees":"","Repeated":"-","UserName":"tsa","url":"Javascript:"},{"id":"4E7E7C5A-04EA-4090-BCFB-5D3002233663","resourceId":"1","start":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.006Z","title":"project","UserID":"6","Attendees":"","Repeated":"-","UserName":"tsd","url":"Javascript:"}]"` This is not valid code. Remove the double quotes from each end.

Comment: Also why do you say you call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', MeetingArrayDisplay);`? Where do you do this? It should be unnecessary since you defined the events in the `events:` option in config already, and also "renderEvent" renders a _single_ event, not an array of events. So once you fix the syntax error in your event array, and remove this redundant method call, it ought to work. If that definiition of MeetingArrayDisplay is really an accurate copy of what's in your real code, then there's no possibility that you don't have a console error

Comment: yes i removed that quotes but then also it is not displaying

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/5/ (using your code for MeetingArrayDisplay, and not working - check the browser console to see the error, which _must_ have been in your real code, despite what you said) and compare with http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/6/ (working, although I had to add some arbitrary resources, because you didn't tell us those - that could also be a source of problems - and also I had to wind the default date back to 1970 because that's when your events are scheduled for, according to the JSON)

Comment: also in your example code you have the calendar HTML twice. Is that just an error in your example? Because it's invalid HTML to have two elements with the same `id` attribute, and it makes no logical sense either.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake but it is not twise

Comment: ok no problem. What about the calendar code? Did you see the difference in my two examples? Also I would guess that your JSON is wrong and the events should not be in 1970? If so you'd have to fix whatever code is generating the event data.

Comment: yes i think it is a date format issue so i am looking in that. Thank you.. @ADyson

Comment: ok, I wrote up the original problem as an answer, which I'd be grateful it would consider marking as accepted. The date format thing is not really part of the question directly, since you didn't show the code and also the calendar "works" despite that, even though the events are perhaps not in the place you intended them to be, they are visible nevertheless.

Comment: It is date format issue and i did not add  media="print" for fullcalendar.print.css. so it was silly mistake from my side but now it is solved for me.

Comment: @DhrutiRathod ok great, well if you would consider accepting the given answer in that case, as discussed, I would be grateful. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a syntax error in your event array. Remove the quote marks (`"`) from the beginning and end of the variable:

```
MeetingArrayDisplay ="[{"id":"09CCDDE2-75FA-401A-B52D-23094809D3BF","resourceId"‌​:"1","start":"1970-0‌​1-01T00:00:00.006Z",‌​"end":"1970-01-01T00‌​:00:00.006Z","title"‌​:"Weekly project review meeting","UserID":"6","Attendees":"","Repeated":"-","UserNam‌​e":"tsa","url":"Java‌​script:"},{"id":"4E7‌​E7C5A-04EA-4090-BCFB‌​-5D3002233663","reso‌​urceId":"1","start":‌​"1970-01-01T00:00:00‌​.006Z","end":"1970-0‌​1-01T00:00:00.006Z",‌​"title":"project","U‌​serID":"6","Attendee‌​s":"","Repeated":"-"‌​,"UserName":"tsd","u‌​rl":"Javascript:"}]";
```

becomes

```
MeetingArrayDisplay =[{"id":"09CCDDE2-75FA-401A-B52D-23094809D3BF","resourceId"‌​:"1","start":"1970-0‌​1-01T00:00:00.006Z",‌​"end":"1970-01-01T00‌​:00:00.006Z","title"‌​:"Weekly project review meeting","UserID":"6","Attendees":"","Repeated":"-","UserNam‌​e":"tsa","url":"Java‌​script:"},{"id":"4E7‌​E7C5A-04EA-4090-BCFB‌​-5D3002233663","reso‌​urceId":"1","start":‌​"1970-01-01T00:00:00‌​.006Z","end":"1970-0‌​1-01T00:00:00.006Z",‌​"title":"project","U‌​serID":"6","Attendee‌​s":"","Repeated":"-"‌​,"UserName":"tsd","u‌​rl":"Javascript:"}];
```

Now it's a valid array. Before it was un-parseable.

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/6/ for a working example.